# How to track a jar with Maven?

Tags: maven, dependencies, dependency-management

I am using maven from command line to build my application, and i get build success, but in eclipse i get the error:

```
The repository system is offline but the artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:1.2 is not available in the local repository.
```

Although i made update project configuration and update dependencies, i want to know what plugin or dependency is responsible for this jar ?

following are the plugins i am using:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>hbm2ddl</goal> 
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <components>
                        <component>
                            <name>hbm2ddl</name>
                            <implementation>annotationconfiguration</implementation>
                        </component>
                        <component>
                            <name>hbmdoc</name>
                        </component>
                    </components>
                    <componentProperties>
                        <configurationfile>/target/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
                        <outputfilename>CreateTables.sql</outputfilename>
                        <namingstrategy>com.xeno.advertisingsuite.web</namingstrategy>
                        <drop>false</drop>
                        <create>true</create>
                        <export>false</export>
                        <format>true</format>
                    </componentProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- run command: mvn tomcat7:run -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- run command: mvn 7:run -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.t7mp</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-t7-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tomcatHttpPort>8081</tomcatHttpPort>
                    <tomcatShutdownPort>8008</tomcatShutdownPort>
                    <tomcatVersion>7.0.22</tomcatVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

<plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <aspectLibraries>
          <aspectLibrary>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
          </aspectLibrary>
        </aspectLibraries>
        <Xlint>warning</Xlint> 
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>test-compile</goal> 
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>


     </plugins>
```

please advise how to fix that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to resolve plugin dependencies by `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins` - it will print dependency tree of maven plugins to output.

Also option which turns debug mode helps greatly: `mvn -X`

Comment: Try to search for the plexus-archiver id in *.pom files of your local repository (~/.m2/repository)

Comment: in my .m2 there are other versions of this jar not the required one, i want to know what plugin exactly asks for this jar so i can change it.

Comment: You can grep usage with exact version: grep -r --include="*.pom" "<artifactId>plexus-archiver<artifactId>\s<version>1.2</version>"

Comment: Also `mvn` -u option and removing of last updated marks (*.lastUpdated files) helps to update dependencies